# How to make two different objects at different speeds "bounce back", only when they reach a certain point

Tags: vb.net

I think from the title itself you can tell I'm an absolute **noob** at this. My code causes the two blocks to move and loop themselves, but since "speedone" is going at 1 integer per 50 milliseconds, and "speedtwo" is going at 3 integers, speedone never bounces to the end before it bounces back.

How do I make it so the blocks only "bounce" back once they hit the end (<80)? Sorry for any bothers^^

```
    log_speeds:
    'one and two are pre determined
    Randomize()

    one = 1

    two = 3

    three = random_int(1, 3)

    four = random_int(1, 3)

    five = random_int(1, 3)

    six = random_int(1, 3)

    seven = random_int(1, 3)

    eight = random_int(1, 3)

    nine = random_int(1, 3)

    ten = random_int(1, 3)

    GoTo enemies

    Console.Clear()
```

enemies:

```
    Do
        Do
            speedone = speedone + one
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedone, 2)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            Console.Write(Space(3))
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedone + 3, 2)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
            Console.Write(Space(5))
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedone + 8, 2)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            Console.Write(Space(3))

            speedtwo = speedtwo + two
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedtwo, 4)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            Console.Write(Space(3))
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedtwo + 3, 4)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
            Console.Write(Space(5))
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedtwo + 8, 4)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            Console.Write(Space(3))

            Sleep(50)

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
        Loop Until speedone And speedtwo > 80
        Do
            speedone = speedone - one
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedone, 2)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            Console.Write(Space(3))
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedone + 3, 2)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
            Console.Write(Space(5))
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedone + 8, 2)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            Console.Write(Space(3))

            speedtwo = speedtwo - two
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedtwo, 4)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            Console.Write(Space(3))
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedtwo + 3, 4)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black
            Console.Write(Space(5))
            Console.SetCursorPosition(speedtwo + 8, 4)
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            Console.Write(Space(3))

            Sleep(50)

            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
        Loop Until speedone And speedtwo < 5
    Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You must keep track of what every object does separately and at each game loop perform only a tiny step for each object

Do this

```
Do
    For Each object in the list of objects
        Perform next step
    Loop
Loop
```

I.e., you must keep track of the current state for each object to know what to do next at each loop.

Create objects using a class that look roughly like this

```
Public Class GameObject
    Public Property Speed As Integer
    Public Property Position AS Integer
End Class
```

Add all objects to a `List(Of GameObject)` (can be more than 2).

Perform the next step like this (remember, this is in the loop "For Each object in the list of objects")

```
If obj.Speed > 0 Then
    Calculate next Speed and Position for this object going forward.
    If obj reaches the end Then
        'Bounce off the end
        obj.Speed = -obj.Speed
    End If
Else
    Calculate next Speed and Position for this object going backward.
    If obj reaches the start Then
        'Bounce off the start
        obj.Speed = - obj.Speed
    End If
End If
```

Now, all objects bounce independently.

Calculating the next Position can be as simple as `obj.Position = obj.Position + obj.Speed`.